# Data attribute value not changed after updating it in $.post() callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with reading a specific `data` attribute right after it's set in `$.post()` callback. General example follows.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="my-elem" data-id="0"><div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $elem = $('#my-elem');

console.log($elem.data('id')); // Outputs: 0

$.post('/update-stuff', data, function(response) {
    if (response) {
        $elem.data('id', '1'); // Update data value
    }
});

console.log($elem.data('id')); // Still outputs: 0 <= WRONG
```

If I do the same operation without the Ajax call, and read `data-id`, it outputs `1`:

```
var $elem = $('#my-elem');

console.log($elem.data('id')); // Outputs: 0

$elem.data('id', '1'); // Update data value

console.log($elem.data('id')); // Outputs: 1 <= CORRECT
```

Why doesn't `data` setting work in `$.post()` callback?

Comment: Put the console log in the post, right after the update. You are outputting the result before the post is complete

Comment: `post` is async function, but you use `console.log` before you get the result.

Comment: What do you expect response to be in this case?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I, indeed, was reading the value of `data` too soon. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Post call is asynchronous. In below code, #3 is executed before #2 and hence you are not seeing it being updated even though the value has changed.

```
$.post('/update-stuff', data, function(response) {
    if (response) {
        $elem.data('id', '1'); // #2
    }
});

console.log($elem.data('id')); // #3
```

You have to use `.done()` or `.success()`

```
$.post('/update-stuff', data, function(response) {
    if (response) {
        $elem.data('id', '1'); // Update data value
    }
}).done(function(){
  console.log($elem.data('id'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this. What I don't get is why do I need to use *both* anonymous callback in `$.post()` AND the chained `.done()` callback method. Shouldn't the anonymous one be sufficient? It's called when the ajax request succeeds.

Comment: you don't **have** to use `.done()` per se. But in the above code, result of #3 depends on the execution of #2. And #3 will execute before #2 which is not expected behavior (at least as per the code above). But otherwise $elem.data('id', '1') works, just that the execution of the code is not in happening as expected